# RxAndroid + Retrofit callTimeout doesn't trigger onError

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, okhttp, rx-android

I am using RxAndroid + Retrofit to make http request. Code looks like below:

```
Interceptor headerInterceptor = getHeaderInterceptor();
        HttpLoggingInterceptor httpLoggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        httpLoggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .callTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .addInterceptor(headerInterceptor)
                .addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor)
                .build();

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();

        sRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .client(client)
                .build();
```

Use it like this:

```
ApiProvider.provideApi(MyApi.class)
                .submit(id, mRequest)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(
                        response -> {
                            Log.w("tag", "success");
                        },
                        throwable -> {
                            Log.w("tag", "error");
                        }
                );
```

I set `connectTimeout / readTimeout / writeTimeout` to be 60 seconds, and set `callTimeout` to be 5 seconds.

I know this configuration may be not reasonable but I just want to get a timeout exception after 5 seconds, and the `Log.w("tag", "error");` could be called.

However, I found this line will never be called for my testing. And if I set `connectionTimeout` to 1 second, then this line will be called immediately.

So what I should do if I want callTimeout to trigger the log error line?

Comment: try to add `.retryOnConnectionFailure(false)`

Comment: 5 seconds call timeout is pretty very less...go for around 50sec or 1min.

Comment: @AntonisRadz tried `retryOnConnectionFailure(false)`, doesn't work. but thank you all the same!

Comment: @PrajwalW umm, I agree 5 seconds is too short, but the code works well if I set connection timeout to 1 second, I can get the `onError` called. Thank you!

Comment: As u mentioned it seems that the connect timeout shld be lesser than the call timeout. Try this once pls. Set calltimeout value > connect timeout value.

Comment: @PrajwalW I set connection timeout to 5 and call timeout to 8. It still doesn't get called. Any other suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: You could try to enter an invalid url, where no Webserver is running. Then the call should timeout

Comment: @J.Gerbershagen thanks for your comment. umm but, why I shall try with an invalid url? For real cases, the url should be valid, is it?

Comment: The syntax of the url should be valid. But on the target host, no http server should be running. Then you get a guaranteed timeout.

Comment: @J.Gerbershagen thanks for your comment. Regarding `But on the target host, no http server should be running`, I don't think that is the purpose of `callTimeout` to deal with. callTimeout should be some case that the app/client cannot get the response in the specific time, it could be the issue of network status is awful or the server is too busy to handle it in that short time. But thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally find the the cause.

I was using `com.jakewharton.retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.RxJava2CallAdapterFactory`, which had been deprecated per its readme: https://github.com/JakeWharton/retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter

```
This is now DEPRECATED!

Retrofit 2.2 and newer have a first-party call adapter for RxJava 2: https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-adapters/rxjava2
```

After switching to `retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.RxJava2CallAdapterFactory`, everything start working nicely.

And BTW for any guy who might be interested in what the differences are between them two? Attach the key info I found below:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As for as I can see, I think your problem maybe isn't from how many seconds you set for `callTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)`, I think your maybe Rx stream have already throw some errors, so stream just break you can get any response from here. However, you reset time seconds to 1s, and then you restart app, this time stream not break and you get error. 
So simple re-test it again to make sure your stream won't break even before enter this subscribe.

And I have been test with some stupid implementations:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val delayInterceptor = object : Interceptor {
        override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): okhttp3.Response {
            Thread.sleep(6000L)
            return chain.proceed(chain.request())
        }

    }
    val client: OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .callTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .addInterceptor(delayInterceptor)
            .build()

    val retrofit: Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://en.wikipedia.org/")
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(client)
            .build();

    data class Wiki(
            @SerializedName("type")
            val type: String
    )

    interface WikiService {
        @GET("api/rest_v1/page/random/summary")
        fun getRandomSummary(): Single<Wiki>
    }

    @SuppressLint("CheckResult")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        retrofit.create(WikiService::class.java)
                .getRandomSummary()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe({
                    Log.d("tag", "success")
                }, {
                    Log.e("tag", "error")
                })
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! Could you please help confirm the `Log.e("tag", "error " + it)`, where the `it` refers to `InterruptedIOException: timeout`? As if the callback is triggered by callTimeout it should be this error rather than others. And there might be more than 1 reasons to trigger onError such as `SocketTimeoutException` (caused by connectionTimeout) or ClassCastException if the response is not a json object but a pure string.. Thanks for your help!!